# Multibinding, converter and stringformat

Tags: wpf, xaml, converters, multibinding, string-formatting

I have a problem with the following example:

```
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="Value and percent: {0:N0}, {1:p0}">
                <Binding Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}"
                         ConverterParameter="12"
                         Path="ValueA" />
                <Binding Path="ValueB" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
```

ValueA and ValueB are doubles. My problem is that ValueA is not displayed according to string format (N0), but ValueB is (displayed correctly with percentage). If I remove the converter both values are displayed correctly. I only have this problem when using a multibinding. It works fine using a single binding.

The converters function is to divide the value by 12, so it returns another double value. I only want to convert one of the values, not both.

I'm using WPF 3.5, is this a known bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You might also show the Convert method. Make sure that it returns a `double`, not a `string`.